# Dropbox Ext4 - ecryptfs

Tags: dropbox, ecryptfs

Will Dropbox truly stop working on ecryptfs Nov 2018?? My system is Lubuntu with Home folder secured with ecryptfs. What can be done to ensure Dropbox will still work??

Comment: "ecryptfs is not supported, but Dropbox will continue to sync with supported file systems that are encrypted via full disk encryption (e.g. LUKS)" as per [this](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/system-requirements#desktop).

Comment: Would be great to have a guide to get rid of ecryptfs and switch to LUKS for this purpose

Comment: How were you using ecryptfs with dropbox? Keeping the decrypted files on dropbox? It still supports ext4, why not keep the encrypted ext4 files on dropbox?

Comment: @Xen2050 : If you use your Dropbox to share files with others, having them encrypted in the Dropbox is a bit complicated.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and Dropbox work on my home dir which enabled ecryptfs. Only thing is that I need to do re-sync after the first login. (1) stop the running dropbox; (2) remove the config dir: rm -rf .dropbox (3) restart dropbox

Answer (score 6):

New versions of Dropbox for Linux released after Nov 2018 [only support ext4 with xattr enabled, and do not support ecryptfs](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/Dropbox-client-warns-me-that-it-ll-stop-syncing-in-Nov-why/m-p/290058#M42250) (Ubuntu's encrypted home folders).

I expect if you use [ecryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/) it will continue to work until you update your Dropbox to a newer version with the changes.

The updated Dropbox will work if you stop using ecryptfs or move your Dropbox folder outside of the encrypted directory, though in either of these cases you will need to migrate the files across to the non-encrypted location.

If you require encryption Dropbox will still work on an ext4 partition on top of a block encrypted device, eg using [LUKS](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup).

Note that Dropbox is a third party application not provided by Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 4):

By following [this](https://ebner.wordpress.com/2018/11/15/dropbox-on-linux-with-encrypted-home-directory/) guide I managed to keep the Dropbox folder in my ext4 ecryptfs user home folder. It worked fine on Ubuntu 18.10 without reinstalling Dropbox. I made a few changes to the original guide because i ran into some issues.

### Step 1: create a mount point and make it read-only if not mounted

```
mkdir ~/remote/Dropbox
sudo chattr +i ~/remote/Dropbox
```

Change the “remote” part of the paths if you prefer to place your Dropbox folder at a different location.

### Step 2: create an image file and format it

Change 10G to something that corresponds to the space that you need in order to sync your Dropbox files:

```
truncate -s 10G ~/remote/.Dropbox.ext4
```

Format the image with ext4:

```
mkfs.ext4 -F ~/remote/.Dropbox.ext4
```

### Step 3: create an entry in /etc/fstab

```
/home/<username>/remote/.Dropbox.ext4 /home/<username>/remote/Dropbox ext4 user,noauto,rw,loop,x-gvfs-hide 0 0
```

We use the parameter x-gvfs-hide to avoid showing the folder in sidebar of the file manager.

### Step 4: use a systemd user service to mount the Dropbox image

Create an new file

```
touch ~/.config/systemd/user/mountdropbox.service
```

edit the file with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mounts a Dropbox ext4 image in the home directory of a user
After=home-<username>.mount
Requires=home-<username>.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/mount %h/remote/Dropbox
ExecStop=/bin/umount %h/remote/Dropbox
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Now lets enable and start the service. Slashes must be replaced by dashes if used as systemd parameters.

```
systemctl --user enable mountdropbox.service
systemctl --user start mountdropbox.service
```

We also make sure that we own the mounted folder:

```
sudo chown <username>:<username> ~/remote/Dropbox
```

Rename old dropbox folder (i.e. `/home/<username>/Dropbox`)

```
mv -iv ~/Dropbox ~/Dropbox_old
```

Create a new symbolic link at the original dropbox path (i.e. `/home/<username>/Dropbox`)

```
cd ~ && ln -vs ~/remote/Dropbox Dropbox
```

run dropbox

```
dropbox start -i
```

### Step 5: mount the folder before the start of dropbox

in Dropbox preferences, untick the option **Start Dropbox on startup**

Create a new file and make it executable

```
touch ~/remote/start_dropbox.sh
chmod +x ~/remote/start_dropbox.sh
```

Edit file and add this content

```
#!/bin/sh
systemctl --user enable mountdropbox.service
systemctl --user start mountdropbox.service
dropbox start -i
```

Rename the original autostart file of dropbox (otherwise dropbox will overwrite it with the original content)

```
mv -iv ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop ~/.config/autostart/start_dropbox.desktop
```

Edit the file and modify the Exec Property

```
Exec=/home/<username>/remote/start_dropbox.sh
```

Comment: this is quite overkill. Check this: https://blog.burke-consulting.net/dropbox-now-requiring-non-encrypted-ext4-on-linux-solution/

Comment: I was also wondering; why all the extra steps besides just adding the mount point to `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I've just put my dropbox folder in /media and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I used this as the impetus to set up a Nextcloud server and use that instead of Dropbox. You could also consider SpiderOak, Box etc. 
I don't really understand Dropbox's motivation for doing this. They say that they need the file attribute tools available on ext4, but those work fine on encrypted filesystems too. Anyway, time to find something better.

Answer (score 0):

This (cha4on) is awesome. I tried the simpler solutions above and they just hung my kubuntu 18.04 . I am not sure why people find it such overkill, for me it not only worked beautifully but it was also a great tutorial. I loved the fstab line and the systemctl's in particular. Only one thing - the way it's done, for me the dropbox program itself will not link to /remote/Dropbox - possibly because is a drive not a specific directory? I had to make it have /remote/Dropbox/Dropbox as a dropbox home, with the corresponding correction to the symbolic link to the /home/

Comment: I think you mean my answer.